# Moving yii project to another machine

Tags: php, yii, frameworks, migrating

I have a project, build in `Yii Framework` , in my machine 1. 
Now I moved my whole project to new laptop.

But it's not running and displaying some error:

```
Warning: require_once(D:\xampp\htdocs\rpadmin/../framework/yii.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\rpadmin\index.php on line 11
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'D:\xampp\htdocs\rpadmin/../framework/yii.php' (include_path='.;D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\xampp\htdocs\rpadmin\index.php on line 11
```

Does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: Do you have xampp installed in D:\xampp on the new machine? It seems you either do not have it installed at all or you have it somewhere else.

Comment: set file permission to 755

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually u have folder of yii(framework named folder) framework outside the rpadmin folder now u have to upload it from your local machine to the server and put it outside the rpadmin from... the error message ...

**Warning: require_once(D:\xampp\htdocs\rpadmin/../framework/yii.php):**

so there will be a framework named folder....

after that make some changes

1. Give rpadmin/protected/runtime permission 777
2. If its ISS the you have to give rpadmin/assets folder permission 777
3. change the required settings in rpadmin/protected/config/main.php if theres only like db connection

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit in your project the file `index.php`  and change the line:

```
// change the following paths if necessary
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';
```

with your `Yii Framework` path location.
If you have `framework` folder in the same location with the project, you need to change like this:

```
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/framework/yii.php';
```